# React Array props changing when rendering

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-hooks, antd

When passing props to react functions(Component) and then passing it to useState constant, anytime the useState constant changes, the original props value also change.

My Components now uses react-hooks and functions I'm passing my props directly as function argument object. I'll like to keep these props unchanged since I'll use it when submitting to the server. I stored it  in useState so I can work with it. `"react": "^16.8.6"`

```
  const [options, setOptions] = useState(model.options);
  const [value, setValue] = useState([]);

  function handleRadioCheck(index, arg) {
    const argValue = arg.target.value;

    const newValue = [...value];
    newValue[index] = argValue;
    setValue([...newValue]);

    const newOptions = [...options];
    newOptions[index].answer = argValue;
    setOptions([...newOptions]);

  }

  return (
    <>
      {options.map((option, i) =>
                <Radio.Group key={i} style={radioStyle} onChange={(value) => handleRadioCheck(i, value)} value={value.length > 0 ? value[i] : 'none'}>
                  <Radio value="none" disabled style={{ display: "none" }} />
                  <Radio value={true}> Yes </Radio>
                  <Radio value={false}> No <span style={{ paddingLeft: '30%' }}>{option.option}</span> </Radio>
                </Radio.Group>
              )}
    </>
  )
}

I expect only options to change and not model.options.
```

Comment: `const newOptions = [...options];` creates new array but elements are still objects from `model.options`

Comment: Yeah, but that does not explain why `model.options` is also changing when doing  `setOptions([...newOptions]);`. I'm actually just copying the options array for transformation.

Comment: But you also modify those objects doing `newOptions[index].answer = argValue;` which is same as doing `model.options[index].answer = argValue;` because the objects in new array are the same

Comment: But they are two different arrays, right? Or are you saying using `setOptions` should modify both arrays? My intention is to modify only the `options` array wish should be a copy of `model.options`.

Comment: `const arr=[{id:1},{id:2}] ; const copy = [...arr]` ... the copy is  shallow copy and `arr[0]===copy[0]`. So when the elements are objects they are references to same object. `arr[0].id=100` makes `copy[0].id ===100` since they are the same object

Comment: You should accept people answers which were helpful, please take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: Sry I upvoted instead of validating...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you could do is destructure the object into a new object rather than mutate original

```
const newOptions = [...options];
newOptions[index] = {...newOptions[index], answer: argValue} ;
setOptions(newOptions);
```

Comment: Thanks this is working. I needed to differentiate between `shallow-copy` where both array point to the same slots and `deep-copy` where each array has its own slots.